# Passing an object/field to a javascript function: this.[Control] vs this.form.[control]

Tags: javascript, html

JavascriptScript:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum){
            if (limitField.value.length > limitNum)
                limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
            else{
                if (limitCount != null)
                    limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

This works:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <textarea name="myTextArea" id="myTextArea" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.myTextArea, this.form.remCount, 10);"></textarea>
    <label name="remCount" id="remCount"></label>
</form>
```

but this doesn't:

```
<textarea name="myTextArea" id="myTextArea" onKeyDown="limitText(this.myTextArea, this.remCount, 10);"></textarea>
    <label name="remCount" id="remCount">Chars Left </label>
```

Using Chrome to debug it, if I don't use the form method, then the `limitField` and `limitCount` are null, but in `this.myTextArea` is not. Is there anyway to use the function without  enclosing the fields in a form? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass `this` by itself. It'll be the element itself. To find the "count" label, you can always use `document.getElementById()` to find it.

Also, though this isn't part of your question: be aware that browsers report different values for the length of a textarea when the value includes hard line breaks; that is, line breaks that are present due to the user typing the "Enter" key.  Some browsers treat line breaks as being worth 2 characters, because in fact they *are* two characters long when a `<textarea>` is posted back to the server from a form. However, some browsers only report a line break as being 1 character long, even though they follow the relevant spec and send the `<textarea>` value back with 2-character line breaks.

Modern browsers support the `maxlength` attribute on `<textarea>` elements, but for the reasons outlined above it doesn't work properly in Chrome and Firefox (though I think a fix is working its way through WebKit).

Comment: Also, I didn't even think about the new line characters, would this be an appropriate fix:

if (limitField.value.replace("\n", "").length > limitNum)

if (limitCount != null)
      limitCount.innerText = limitNum - limitField.value.replace("\n", "").length;

or would doing that much string parsing be inefficient?

Comment: Well yes you basically have to look at the value of the field and check for solitary "\n" characters not preceded by "\r".  If you find those (as you will in Firefox), just add the number of them to the length to get the *true* length.